# javascript conditions on input in forms

Tags: javascript

So this is my code:

```
<html>

<body>

<p>13-7: <input id="answer" type="text"" /><button onclick="check(6, bla)">Tjek!</button></p>
<p id="bla"></p>
<p>20-7: <input id="answer" type="text"" /><button onclick="check(13, bla2)">Tjek!</button></p>
<p id="bla2"></p>



<script type="text/javascript">

function check(svar, ud)
{
var answer,vurdering;
answer=document.getElementById("answer").value;
vurdering=(answer==svar)?"Correct":"Wrong";
document.getElementById('ud').innerHTML=vurdering;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click the button, I think it should display wether the input was or wasn't equal to the answer (svar). But when inserting 'ud' in the getElementById() instead of the paragraph id, it wont display whether the input was correct or wrong. any advice?

Comment: Should be passing the IDs as strings, not variables: onclick="check(6, 'blah')"

Comment: also should be `document.getElementById(ud)` not 'ud'

Comment: You have two "answer" ids, they should be unique.

Comment: Change bla to 'bla' and bla2 to 'bla2'

Comment: You had an extra quote on the inputs -- working fiddle posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hErPP/

The id field needs to be unique in HTML.  Here is an example that solves this problem.
Also `bla` and `bla2` needed to be strings.
(Your code might have other problems)

```
<html>
<body>

<p>13-7: <input id="answer1" type="text" /><button onclick="check('answer1', 6, 'bla');">Tjek!</button></p>
<p id="bla"></p>
<p>20-7: <input id="answer2" type="text" /><button onclick="check('answer2', 13, 'bla2');">Tjek!</button></p>
<p id="bla2"></p>​




<script type="text/javascript">

function check(id, svar, ud)
{
  var answer,vurdering;
  answer=document.getElementById(id).value;
  vurdering=(answer==svar)?"Correct":"Wrong";
  document.getElementById(ud).innerHTML=vurdering;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change to this `check(6, 'bla')` and in the function you need to remove the two quotes of `document.getElementById('ud').innerHTML=vurdering` and change to this `document.getElementById(ud).innerHTML=vurdering`